# n8n on railway.app generating localhost webhook URLs

Tags: webhooks, railway, n8n

I'm running the n8n software from github on railway.app

The thing is, when using webhook nodes from n8n, the test and production URLs generated are localhost links

**So my questions are:**

1. Is this normal? To have localhost URLs although running the software via railway.app
2. Are these URLs listenable? Can n8n really listen through these URLs?
   *I tried these URLs with supabase webhooks and it didn't work, but I'm still newbie to these environments so I can't really decide whether it's because of the localhost links or is there's something wrong I did while setting up the hook*
3. If these URLs are not listenable, How can I overcome this problem through railway.app itself? or Must I use services like ngrok?

I expected railway to have the software 100% online including the links that are generated from the software